# Open Type in Eclipse not showing multiple files of the same name

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I have 2 almost identical projects open. Most of the the times I'll have files with the same name in both ones and I'll want to copy data from one to other manually.

I use the Open Type dialog(CTRL + ALT + T) A LOT (can't live without it) and the first I noticed is that when I search for class X that is available in both projects it'll show up only one of them :(

I've even tried putting each one of the projects in different worksets but that doesn't seem to be of any help.

Will the only way to handle this to create 2 different workspaces in 2 running Eclipse instances?

Comment: refresh the workspace once. because it works fine for me.

Comment: You are indeed right, it will show both! But now i've noticed something ugly, again. It seems that it will always pick the file from the first project, ignoring my actual selected project.

Comment: JDT would remember the one preferred by you when you search the X in the Open Type again.

Comment: Use the **Open Resource** (Ctrl + Shift + R) instead, much easier for your work.

Answer (score 2):

An annoying problem with an easy fix:
Remove your *.index files in /.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core

Answer (score 0):

We've run into this with a fork in plugin development, with 2 different versions of the same plugin.  We can check out both versions at the same time (giving one of them a different name), but on each session startup eclipse will pick one of them as the one to use (in my case, causing compile errors half the time).

The workaround I use:

1. create a project, oldVersions
2. Check out the older version of the
   project using Check Out As..., into
   oldVersions instead of the default location
3. Now it is not on the classpath, and
   so it won't interfere with Open Type
   or compiling.

Then I use Open Resource as mentioned by @lschin any time I want the old version file.